# Upvoted Offensive Post

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags, offensive

I just flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214053/drag-and-drop-images-from-another-website-to-mine/27428040#27428040) post as offensive, and I noticed that, before I flagged it, there were two upvotes on it. Since it was a late answer on an old post, I feel it's unlikely that the answer was stellar enough to garner two upvotes and then be edited to this all within the grace period. Therefore, it was probably voted up while in its offensive (or at very least entirely useless) state

Is there any investigation that will (or should) be done into the source of these upvotes?

Comment: @AirThomas If it's the one I'm thinking of, it's been nuked. There's not much to see there, and certainly nothing to upvote.

Comment: @AirThomas You really don't need to see a screenshot. Trust me.

Comment: @bluefeet Uh-oh. Now you've got me *really* curious!

Comment: @AirThomas - It is just a block of a few hundred Unicode swastika characters and the phrase *"I'm NOT DONE!"* written underneath it.  There is no reason to go add this into the question here because it is irrelevant.  The important part is that some people upvoted an offensive post, not what the offensive content was.

Comment: Judging by the number of similar deleted answers (spanning some months), I think that question ought to be protected so whoever is harassing the OP can't keep registering new accounts and posting junk.

Comment: @iCodez Fair enough.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - That should have kicked in automatically, but thanks for the reminder.

Comment: On the bright side, at least people are learning about Unicode.

Comment: @BilltheLizard True. I had no idea Unicode had a swastika. Seems a bit niche...

Comment: Very well reviewed.

Comment: @iCodez on the contrary, the content is extremely relevant; until you told us what it was, I had no reason to think that the upvoters had done anything *wrong* besides having a different opinion on the post's value to the Meta thread's OP, and didn't understand the thread at all. Even leaving aside that people have different standards of offensiveness, a post can simultaneously be *useful* and *pointlessly offensive* (like a post that provides a perfectly correct answer followed by a remark about how the asker is a typical stupid *$askers_race* for not being able to figure it out themselves).

Comment: Wow, the first case when I really see the advantage of protecting a question!

Comment: @StephenTG see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika) for an explanation of the cultural significance of the swastika - it has been considered a good luck symbol in some religions for centuries before the Nazis appropriated it.

Comment: FWIW the Nazi swastika is almost always rotated 45 degrees and the symbol itself has a long history like MattDMo pointed out. In spite of it its stigma, the symbol is not inherently offensive.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yeah, I think I know who voted for that, and we're checking into those accounts now. Let's say this isn't the first time this has happened with this person.

We can't see individual votes on posts like this, but I recognize the account and the pattern of trolling. I've asked for an SE employee to check if my guess is correct, since they don't give out voting information on individual posts, even to us. That's all I can say.

Also, if you happened to have your offensive flag disputed on that, that was me. I killed the post, then the mod menu glitched on me when trying to pull up the review history and I accidentally cleared the flags (disputing them). I apologize for that, my bad.

Comment: No worries about the disputed. I got Marshal a few days back, so I'm slightly less obsessive about my helpful flag count...

Comment: Bad Bra... *cough* UI, very bad!

Comment: Where do these weird trolls come from :/

Comment: @Sunshine - The Internet is a large and diverse place.

Comment: They obviously come from the evil(?) version of Stack Overflow, known as Queue Underflow.

Comment: I feel like I should have been watching this earlier...

Comment: @Compass, Where everyone has a goatee. http://i.imgur.com/g9Bctza.jpg

Comment: We know exactly who this guy is. The two upvotes are certainly sock puppets. Some depressed and unsuccessful troll - pretty funny.