# Raise flag for obvious revenge downvotes

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, voting, tactical-downvoting

I noticed a pattern where after I downvote an answer and leave a comment I get 2-3 downvotes in a row - for example:

[image]

These two are completely unrelated to anything I've done recently, they're inactive and old. The user most likely looked at my questions - picked the ones with the lowest score to seem less suspicious and downvoted them. This is not the first or second or third time this exact pattern has happened to me.

### Feature request

Given users A,B. (Please note the differences from the original proposal)

> If user A downvotes more than one of user B's questions in under 5 minutes and those questions have not had other voting activity in the last 24 hours and user B has downvoted an active question of user A in the last 24 hours. Raise a moderator flag.

### Answers to comment concerns.

- Yes, I'm aware there is already a reversal script - it doesn't catch it.
- I'm not concerned about *my* 4 reputation points, **this pattern can deter users with 100 rep from commenting on bad answers providing crucial and useful information**.
- I'm not fixated on an hour as a threshold, 3-4 minutes might be more appropriate.
- These two have since been manually reverted meaning that the flag would've worked in this case.

Comment: So in addition to the serial downvote system, this would check to see if the two users have had any interactions and counter those votes?

Comment: You are aware there is already a serial voting reversal script, right?

Comment: The Serialization question already had 4 downvotes. Perhaps it's not that good a question? So now we're no longer allowed to indicate that if we recently downvoted anything else from you?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am well aware there is a reversal script, and I'm also well aware it does not catch this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Some people manage to fly under the serial vote reversal scripts radar, and just pick 2-3 questions to downvote and don't do it within the same minute. I've often experienced this.

Comment: related discussions at MSE: [Spiteful downvoting? Two fast DVs to my unrelated posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178703/165773) and [A better serial voting trap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147374/165773)

Comment: If there *is* a pattern here, you can just flag one of those posts for moderator attention (if the votes have not been reverted automatically tomorrow or even if the voting pattern is repeatedly executed even with reversals). They have additional tools to see if there is a pattern of voting that they need to act on.

Comment: @Bart that's an old question and I'd delete it if I could - if you check its counts there is no way someone suddenly became interested in those two obscure and unrelated questions all of a sudden at an interval of a few seconds.

Comment: This probably isn't enough to trip the serial voting watchdogs, but really discourages leaving a comment to go with downvotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - It has to be a solid pattern of many votes over time, though. A couple of lone votes usually requires us to pull in a staff member, and we tend to only do that in extreme cases. Their time is even more limited than ours.

Comment: @MartijnPieters my goal is not to fix _my_ 4 reputation problem as 4 reputation is not a lot for a 50K user. I'd rather try to improve the system as a whole. If this happens to a 100 rep user this will definitely deter him from leaving correct comments in the future.

Comment: I'm not arguing that what you think happened never happens @BenjaminGruenbaum. Just that the vote might well be valid. Even if I specifically look at your content, if I take the time to evaluate it I should be allowed to downvote it if I think that's needed. To outright ban that isn't good. If there is an actual problem, have a moderator/team member check it out.

Comment: @Bart an automatic flag sounds like a legitimate alternative solution.

Comment: @BradLarson: I recently had such a pattern; auto-reversal one day, next day some more downvotes aimed at flying under the radar and after flagging a moderator found the rogue troll account and nuked it. Perhaps that was a special case where that account was on the radar already?

Comment: The reversal process is not likely to kick in for just two downvotes. Here's what you should do: Not worry. At 55k anyway. Even if those two question got downvoted on a bootless incentives, it still helps question/answer sorting; which is all what voting is about. Unless this were exceptionally stellar answers to begin with, this doesn't warrant lengthy discomposure about it. (Else just remind yourself that your downvote fan wasted two points as well.)

Comment: @mario please see my above comments - I'm not worried about the rep at all...

Comment: I'd be more  in favour of that @BenjaminGruenbaum, but then still for possibly more severe cases than this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - The trend has to be clear enough for us to act on. In that case it was, and since it was an identifiable troll we could delete the account ourselves. If it was a legitimate account, that would have required manual vote invalidation. Vote invalidation can only be done by a staff member, and it really has to be worth it. Small vote counts without a more targeted trend generally aren't, and we settle for warnings there.

Comment: @Bart I have experienced this for instance with particular persons, that they tend to give me this pattern (I don't want to disclose here, who's meant), whenever I downvote their answers (e.g. because of answering a VLQ question). Usually those are HR users themselves and are well intelligent enough to pick up my worst questions or answers. Though even these may deserve a downvote judged by content, the behavioral pattern smells (a lot).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is exactly what I'm talking about in this question.

Comment: Sure @πάνταῥεῖ, I'm not arguing it doesn't happen. I have had "obvious choices" downvoted as well after particular interactions. But the measures initially proposed still don't get my vote.

Comment: Regarding your edit, "this pattern can deter users with 100 rep from commenting on bad answers providing crucial and useful information." I really doubt 100 rep users would even be aware of such a pattern yet.

Comment: There is a morale on this: never leave comments.

Comment: That moral is exactly what I'd like to prevent with this suggestion

Comment: Seems like this **is** targeted by a long time troll. [this message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27430405/829835) (deleted) indicates these were targeted, myself  benji and sterling have all been serial voted today and now I'm getting multiple messages from said user. The user has been removed and my votes remain, so I *presume* they are using multiple accounts. [*this is 100% speculation based on the information I have in front of me*]

Comment: [Another troll? :(](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280025/upvoted-offensive-post#comment128642_280032)

Comment: @Braiam _"There is a morale on this: never leave comments."_ Even if I don't leave a comment, when a VLQ question was closed by me (alone with mjölnir, or along the four other guys), it becomes pretty obvious, I was involved.

Comment: @Sunshine some people have very little to do it seems.

Comment: @Sunshine For the record, the 'troll user' I am dealing with also seems to have two 'friends' to upvote his stuff. BTW thankyou for the link. It does seem very much related.

Comment: /OT @Sunshine with what magic are you using to link to another comment? Edit - OH MY GOD I DIDN"T KNOW I COULD DO THAT.

Comment: @Compass do you know BTW that one can even [link comment to itself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280040/raise-flag-for-obvious-revenge-downvotes#comment128677_280040 "example - click me")? :)

Comment: Well, I just lost my ability to cast close votes due to a revenge downvote... Probably being able to post comments anonymously would partially solve the problem.

Comment: Im having a similar issue. My questions are being flagged and given -1 downvotes recently. Even old topics.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think we can make the assumption that these are revenge downvotes. Are they most likely? Probably. Does that always invalidate two downvotes against a user who recently DV'd them? **Not necessarily**, at least by my understanding of the purpose of voting.

My understanding is that downvotes are intended on Stack Overflow (not Meta) to indicate poor quality, incorrect information, non-answers, or bad practices/unnecessary complexity (like someone suggesting jQuery to change the background-color of a div).

The point here is that, while I haven't looked at your two downvoted answers to see if they are in fact downvote-worthy, there shouldn't be an automated process to revert downvotes in this scenario, because you *can't prove* that they were revenge votes, or that they **weren't** just valid downvotes that happened because a user was brought to their attention through your comment.

**EDIT:**  As far as I can tell from my time on meta, there is no community consensus on when "enough is enough" with regard to downvotes. That is, the community hasn't yet said that twenty downvotes (for example) is enough and should be a bottom limit. In the same manner, there are very few restrictions on how users are supposed to behave. We can spend our time lurking, or answering questions, or asking questions, or both, or in chat, or reviewing all the queues, or simply voting. So this I think would be a dangerous first step in telling users how they are allowed to spend their time here on Stack Overflow.

I think the mentioned time frame in your question is far too broad for the amount of activity here; one hour is enough time to examine at least a dozen questions at length. So if you were suggesting the action be taken when this behavior occurs within a time frame of a few minutes, I would be more inclined to agree.

Further, I think your comment above that recommends an **automatic flag rather than an automatic reversal** is much more reasonable, because my main concern is that I think it takes a human's discerning eye to really decide whether such actions should be cause for concern or are good and valid.

I'm not ready to say I'm sold on these parameters, but an automatic flag on more than two downvotes within a time frame of a matter of minutes would be a much more reasonable solution.

As flags, they'd be brought to moderator attention, but I wonder if there shouldn't be an additional review queue for such things available at 10K or some higher rep level for trusted power users to weigh in on.

Comment: We can't make these assumptions anyway - a user downvoting 15 questions could be just thinking those are bad questions anyway and those are reverted.

Comment: Also note - those are always downvoted _questions_ and not answers since downvoting answers costs reputation.

Comment: If they do so in a space of time where we can be pretty sure there wasn't actual evaluation going on @BenjaminGruenbaum.

Comment: Which they did, in this case and in previous cases - again, I'm more concerned about this pattern deterring users from commenting on downvoted answers than anything else.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The question is at what point does it become targeting? The serial downvoting script considers that threshold to be somewhere around 3-4 (we obviously can't know for sure). While, yes, your suggestion does attempt to remove false positives, it lowers that key threshold to two, which I think is just too few. An hour is a *long* time for two questions (or answers). If it were within a time frame of like three or four minutes, you might have a stronger case, in my opinion.

Comment: An automatic flag is not viable for something like this. As I describe in my comments on the question, moderators cannot invalidate votes so there's nothing we can do. These flags would be worthless. An SE employee would have to review all these, and frankly it isn't worth their limited time unless it gets to be large-scale vote targeting of a user. At that point, we'll already be aware of it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it's not always downvoting of answers. I got trolled a few times with a clear pattern of downvoting old answers (over 2 years ago). This is not a coincidence: when you get 3 in a row and all of them old it means that someone had to dig in your history... as for the claim that maybe someone thought it's a bad answer, again it's highly unlikely that an answer that had 34 upvotes and 0 downvotes (from two years back) would suddenly get reviewed by someone that thinks it's a bad answer. Let along 3 such answers in a row...