# What on earth is this Stack Bot doing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spam

[This account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4356904/stackbot) has just appeared, and started "answering" questions by posting stuff from the FAQ about why a question has been closed.

Either it's not working properly (since it's claiming to be putting things on hold and hiding them from general view, but it's not actually hiding them or putting them on hold), or, more likely, it's a bad joke that will confuse new users.

Someone nuke it?

It's posting [quite a lot of "answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4356904/stackbot?tab=answers&sort=newest).

---

UPDATE: the accounts keep coming, and keep being deleted. The links I posted were to accounts that have now been incinerated, but for 10K+ users, [here is one of the questions with a deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460875/conversion-from-infix-to-postfix-and-evaluate-it).

---

UPDATE 2: For those wondering whether this is being done by a bot or a human, there's a clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27460880/revisions) (10K+). If you look at the nonsense text at the end, presumably there to make the answer unique, you'll see that it's far from random. It looks exactly like the sort of text you get if you type "randomly" on a QWERTY keyboard. So even if there is a bot involved, it looks like there's at least partial human involvement too.

Comment: Its "answers" seem to have been nuked. Thank goodness.

Comment: @DavidThomas Ah good. I flagged a couple of them, but it was still generating them, so I couldn't flag them all.

Comment: On the plus side, though, it's reassuring to note that, in the event of Skynet taking over, SO bots will be there providing comic relief.

Comment: New troll for the mods to deal with.

Comment: Could this be the proposed [answering bot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275354/what-would-happen-if-i-posted-thoughts-on-how-to-write-a-stack-overflow-robot) at work? In that case, "without being detected as a bot" failed.

Comment: @Jongware I will get round to writing that up... 10 week old baby so haven't had time...

Comment: They are still coming... As much as I hate it, I want to propose disabling anonymous (unregistered) answer to prevent this absurdity until the case has been handled.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion - Not a new troll, pretty sure it's the same one as here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280025/upvoted-offensive-post who's visited us from time to time over the last year. They keep evolving their attacks.

Comment: "the sort of text you get if you type "randomly" on a QWERTY keyboard" -- hye's just drunk!! ;)

Comment: But also, sounds like there's some cool anarchic conspiracy going here, would be nice to participate (wink).

Comment: I didn't follow the _"partial human involvement"_ part. Are you arguing against it being Skynet? I know I wasn't the first to make a Skynet reference, but I thought I was. That's what counts.

Comment: @keyser I meant that the "random" strings didn't look very random, and certainly not like the sort of thing a computer would generate as random text, so they were probably manually typed.

Comment: @chiastic-security It's a good observation, but my initial counter-thought was that such strings could simply have been stored within the bot, or semi-random (avoiding pseudo here). That's why my confusion kicked in at least. Got it now :)

Comment: @animuson glad to see this is now *status-completed*! Can you tell us any more details?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The account was already answer blocked by the time I saw the flags, so thanks to those that down-voted them. If you encounter any more then spam flag the posts. If enough people do this, this will auto-delete the posts without moderator intervention. Please don't use any other flags as these will remain in the flag queue even when the post is deleted.

I've deleted all the "answers" but left the account (for now) so as to keep the OpenID locked.

If they come back with a new OpenID we'll probably destroy the accounts which will help hobble posts from that IP address..

UPDATE: They have come back with a new account on a new IP address so I've nuked both accounts. I will continue to do so as and when they re-appear.

Comment: @PaulCrovella - thanks, now gone, but it's far easier just to flag any posts.

Comment: There appears to be a lot of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stackbot). [One](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4357061/stackbot), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4357058/stackbot), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4357064/stackbot), etc...

Comment: Should we use spam flags in the mean time?

Comment: @Braiam - yes. Spam flags are appropriate in this case.

Comment: @Braiam, Offensive/abusive flags might be a little more suited, and IIRC they feed into the spam system the same way spam flags do.

Comment: @ChrisF It's ongoing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460875/conversion-from-infix-to-postfix-and-evaluate-it :-( ...

Comment: More at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460927/java-8-method-list-add-wrong-result.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ we are aware of this. It's been going on all day

Comment: @ChrisF The irony is, this could even be an intelligent (and even useful) bot whenever able to flag or close vote those questions, but it certainly never will get enough rep starting out like this.

Comment: @πάντα: while I'm not averse to official bots being used on SO, I'd be a little concerned about those bots being provided by unsolicited third-parties.

Comment: @DavidThomas - I doubt there were any real bots involved here.

Comment: As do I, but I was addressing the comment to which I replied, which made the clear speculation that it was a bot.

Comment: I used custom moderator flags in the past when I saw series of posts that looked like ongoing spam attacks. I thought that would help to get them stopped faster. So it's better to just use a plain spam flag on all of the posts?

Comment: @RetoKoradi that's what I did here too. But maybe a spam flag is better: it means the answer can get deleted without needing a mod to get involved. Depends on how fast people add flags, and how fast mods clear their queue, I suppose.

Comment: If someone intentionally playing with SO; then is there a possibility to block the particular domain the IP coming from (OR) probably don't let them create account if the IP matches a pattern (I mean if the IP seems to be from same subnet or alike).